# Take average of values on a particular date

Tags: r

I have a data set that has a number of values for the same date.

```
date    mass    valueone    valuetwo
2013-01-02  12  9.10569191  26.22318268
2013-01-02  15  5.016628265 16.58695984
2013-01-03  20  7.509440899 22.64411354
2013-01-03  25  8.071264267 23.34286118
2013-01-03  30  7.288148403 23.59916115
2013-01-04  11  0.911922812 26.51670265
2013-01-04  13  1.18976903  25.9934597
2013-01-04  22  1.43922472  26.04818726
2013-01-04  24  1.840413213 25.83506966
2013-01-05  33  4.039563656 26.57515907
2013-01-05  25  4.273991585 26.97957993
```

I was hoping to get help with two things.

a) how to take the average of the column "valuetwo" for the date.
b) how to take the weighted average of the column "valueone" by the mass for each date.

Comment: Welcome Reuben. What did you tried? What did you searched?

Comment: Greetings Llopis.  I tried searching in SO for R data averaged by date, but I'm getting a lot of SQL results.  I don't know SQL, and I was hoping to learn how to do this in R.  I don't know how to begin to do this.  I'm new to R and I haven't run across this as a feature in R just yet, so I'm hoping that this is already programmed into R.

Comment: Probably, I don't know if it already programmed but showing what you have tried will help to get answers. If you want to filter for r search: `[r] ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the `plyr` package.

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(date), function(x) mean(x$valuetwo))
ddply(df, .(date), function(x) weighted.mean(x$valueone, x$mass))
```

Comment: shadow you beauty.  Thank you!  That was an elegant answer!